# how to get response body in IOS?

Tags: ios, connection, nsurlconnection, response

Now I want to get the response body. I'm a new guy in IOS developer. I only kown I can use response.statusCode to get httpstatuscode ,such like 400,500 and so on. But how to get response body. Maybe allheaderFileds or data or error.Description?

Comment: What API are you using to get the status code?

Comment: in didReceiveResponse and use response.statusCode

Comment: Sth like:`if response.status_code == 200:                                           data = xmltodict( response.content, [] )`? It's in python

Comment: Not in python. It's in IOS. IOS SDk doesn't have IPA like response.content.

Comment: I assume you mean NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full details are available at: [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

You'll need a object that is the delegate of the `NSURLConnection`. You'll need to have a `receivedData` member variable and you'll need to implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // do something with the data

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```